# if is match on keyword in title, the result is in first order

Tags: elasticsearch

I am really new in elasticsearch and I would like to ask you, hwo do this. For example, I have the documents

```
{ "title": "car", "description" : "something"}
{ "title": "cat", "description" : "car"}
```

and I need if someone searches for term "car" to have in first order documents containing this term in title and then other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/) query that queries multiple fields (title and description), giving a different weight to them.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "car",
            "fields" : [ "title^2", "description" ]
        }
    }
}
```